# Find and Replace Colours in CSS Files from Command Line

Tags: find, replace

I have a load of CSS files in a folder and I want to be able to find and replace different values in all of these files in one go from the command line.

So, for example, if I wanted to replace colour #dadce4 with #ececec can this easily be done with a single command?

Just to be clear, I'm looking for something that will make the changes to all files within a directory and any sub directories without having to specify a file name.

Comment: Use [sed](https://linuxconfig.org/learning-linux-commands-sed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sed  to find and replace text example :
`sed -i 's/dadce4/ececec/g' file.css`
The `g` at the end means that it will replace all colours in the file!, not just first occurrence.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for something that will make the changes to all files within a directory and any sub directories without having to specify a file name.

Comment: You can just pipe all the files you want

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to achieve the desired result.

```
awk '{gsub("dadce4","ececec”,$0);print $0}' filename >>output file
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for something that will make the changes to all files within a directory and any sub directories without having to specify a file name.

Comment: Use Below command it will works .  Worked fine for me                                                                             Find maindirectorypath/* -type f -exec sed -i “s/dadce4/ececec/g” {} \;

Comment: @caned_monkey Kindly vote for my answer if its working

Comment: I've voted for your answer but because I'm a new user it wont change the visible score.